# Can I get typeid from variadic template types without passing args?

Tags: c++

I have a system that saves typeid.name() data in a vector from various class instances,
and another system that creates bitset signatures for required combinations of classes. This signature system has no need to any class instances passed in.

I know how to get typeid.name() from non-variadic template

```
template<class T>
const char* getTypeName() const
{
    return typeid(T).name();
}
```

And I figured how to get typeid.name() from variadic template with args

```
template<class... T> 
void getTypeNames(T... args)
{
    std::vector<const char*> typeNames;
    (typeNames.push_back(typeid(std::forward<T>(args) ).name()), ...  );

    return typeNames;
}
```

But what I would really like to do is something like this:

```
template<class... T> 
void getTypeNames()
{
    std::vector<const char*> typeNames;
    (typeNames.push_back(typeid(std::forward<T>()).name()), ...  );

    return typeNames;
}
```

So is it possible to get typeid like this or do I need to find another way?

PS. first time posting to stackoverflow so sorry if question is too vague or not clear enough.

Comment: Why do you use `typeid(std::forward<T>())` in variadic case, and `typeid(T)` in simple template?

Comment: (typeid(std::forward<T>(args) ).name()),...) works with arguments. In single type case you don't have to forward anything and typeid(T).name() doesn't reguire args. I'm quite new with templates and syntax sometimes seem wierd to me.

Comment: I meant, variadic has special syntax with `...` (that you correctly use). `std::forward` and `typeid`'s usages are unrelated to variadic. It is similar than if you said, I know do addition with 2 variables (`a + b`), but have "issues" with several (`((1 * args) + ... )` ("how I can get rid of `1 *`" that you don't have in simple case)) where you use correct syntax for variadic (which might be problematic/unnatural), but use incorrect/complex syntax for your task.

Comment: If you are asking why I used 'std::forward', then all I can say "Monkey sees, monkey does"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
template<class... T> 
std::vector<const char*> getTypeNames() {
    return {typeid(T).name()...};
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution seems to work exactly as I wanted!