# Print typeids of types in template parameter list

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, fold-expression

I would like to define a function that prints the typeid names of types in its template parameter list. The function accepts no value parameters. So for example calling `print<int>()` should print `int`, `print<int, double>()` should print `int, double` and calling `print<>()` should output the string `no types`.

I have a solution that works, however it uses an extra `vector` to do this, suggested by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65843959/10732434):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class... T>
void print() {
    std::vector<const char*> ids{ typeid(T).name()... };

    if (ids.empty()) {
        std::cout << "no types\n";
        return;
    }

    const auto last = ids.size() - 1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < last; i++)
        std::cout << ids[i] << ", ";

    std::cout << ids[last] << '\n';
}

int main() {
    print<>();
    print<int, double, char>();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, this function isn't very compile-time friendly. I tried to create a version of the code that doesn't involve a vector, however there is a different problem.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Types>
void print() {
    ((std::cout << typeid(Types).name() << ", "), ...);
}

template<>
void print() {
    std::cout << "no types\n";
}

int main() {
    print<>();
    print<int, double, char>();
    return 0;
}
```

*Output*

```
no types
int, double, char,
```

This version is printing a comma after the last type in the template parameter list. I would like to get rid of this comma.

Comment: Beware that there is no guarantee that `typeid(int).name()` is `"int"`. These names are completely implementation-defined and do in fact vary a lot between implementations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have the comma only appear before the type but not after it you could print the first type, then print everything else with the comma **before** the type.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename...Types>
void print_helper() {
    std::cout << typeid(T).name(); // first type
    ((std::cout << ", " << typeid(Types).name()), ...); // everything else
}

template<typename... Types>
void print() {
    print_helper<Types...>();
}

template<>
void print() {
    std::cout << "no types\n";
}

int main() {
    print<>();
    print<int, double, char>();
    return 0;
}
```

```
no types
i, d, c
```

Note that only msvc prints `int`, both clang and gcc use `i` for int, see [typeid](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid).

If you want the approach with the loop, then you can replace the vector with a [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) which does no heap allocations [in the assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/zGvqrbsq3).

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<class... T>
void print() {
    std::array<const char*, sizeof...(T)> ids{ typeid(T).name()... };

    if (ids.empty()) {
        std::cout << "no types\n";
        return;
    }

    const auto last = ids.size() - 1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < last; i++)
        std::cout << ids[i] << ", ";

    std::cout << ids[last] << '\n';
}

int main() {
    print<>();
    print<int, double, char>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of the solution using a loop.